# Rotating Treeview Sideways

Tags: c#, vb.net, user-interface

Well i have created a website ripper that works flawlessly. But a user of mine asked if their was a way to display the website tree. The first thought that came to mind was a tree view.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZmqp.jpg

Though a tree view would work it is not what I would like to put inside my program. I would like to put something along the lines of a telephone chart (or so i think that it is called).

http://img21.imageshack.us/img21/4889/treeview.jpg

Im not sure how to achieve this? Any suggestions?

---

Edit:
What I am looking for is a telephone chain chart OR a phone tree flow chart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use from some components for achieve to what you want.

For example, you can use from **DevComponents.DotNetBar** components. A sample is described in the following:

You can use **TreeGX** control [image: TreeGX control] of *DevComponents.DotNetBar* components on *WinForms* projects in both *C#.NET* and *VB.NET* programming.

This control has some important properties as follows:

- **CellEdit *[Boolean]*:** Indicates whether the label text of the node cells can be edited.

  [image: Editing a Node]
- **CellLayout *[Horizontal, Vertical]*:** Indicates layout of the cells inside the node.
- **CellPartLayout *[Horizontal, Vertical]*:** Indicates layout of the cells inside the node.
- **DragDropEnabled *[Boolean]*:** Indicates whether automatic drag and drop is enabled.

  [image: Drag & Drop]
- **ExpandButtonType *[Ellipse [image: Ellipse Expand Button Type], Image [image: Custom Image Expand Button Type], Rectangle [image: Rectangle Expand Button Type]]*:** Indicates Type of the expand button used to expand/collapse nodes.

  [image: Collapsing a Node]
- **LayoutType *[Diagram, Map]*:** Indicates layout type for the nodes.
- **DiagramLayoutFlow *[LeftToRight, RightToLeft, TopToBottom, BottomToTop]*:** Indicates flow of nodes when Diagram layout is used.
- **MapLayoutFlow *[Spread, LeftToRight, RightToLeft, TopToBottom, BottomToTop]*:** Indicates flow of nodes when Map layout is used.
- **NodesConnector.ConnectorType *[Line [image: Line Connector Type], Curve [image: Curve ConnectorType]]*:** Indicates visual type of the connector.
- **NodesConnector.EndCap *[Arrow [image: Arrow End Cap], Ellipse [image: Ellipse End Cap], None [image: None End Cap]*:** Indicates type of the cap that connector is ended with.
- **NodeStyle.CornerType *[Diagonal [image: Diagonal Corner Type], Rounded [image: Rounded Corner Type], Square [image: Square Corner Type]]*:** Indicates border corner type.

You can see all properties in the following:

(Name), AccessibleDescription, AccessibleName, AccessibleRole, AllowDrop, Anchor, AntiAlias, AutoScroll, BackColor, BackgroundImage, BackgroundImageLayout, CausesValidation, CellEdit, CellLayout, CellPartLayout, CellStyleDefault, CellStyleDisabled, CellStyleMouseDown, CellStyleMouseOver, CellStyleSelected, CenterContent, ColorSchemeStyle, Columns, ColumnStyleMouseDown, ColumnStyleMouseOver, ColumnStyleNormal, CommandBackColor, CommandBackColor2, CommandBackColor2SchemePart, CommandBackColorGradientAngle, CommandBackColorSchemePart, CommandForeColor, CommandForeColorSchemePart, CommandMouseOverBackColor, CommandMouseOverBackColor2, CommandMouseOverBackColor2SchemePart, CommandMouseOverBackColorGradientAngle, CommandMouseOverBackColorSchemePart, CommandMouseOverForeColor, CommandMouseOverForeColorSchemePart, CommandWidth, ContextMenuStrip, Cursor, DefaultCellCursor, DiagramLayoutFlow, DisplayRootNode, Dock, DragDropEnabled, Enabled, ExpandBackColor, ExpandBackColor2, ExpandBackColor2SchemePart, ExpandBackColorGradientAngle, ExpandBackColorSchemePart, ExpandBorderColor, ExpandBorderColorSchemePart, ExpandButtonType, ExpandImage, ExpandImageCollapse, ExpandLineColor, ExpandLineColorSchemePart, Forecolor, GenerateMemeber, Headers, ImageIndex, ImageList, ImeMode, LayoutType, **Location**, Locked, MapLayoutFlow, Modifiers, NodeHorizontalSpacing, Nodes, NodeStyleExpanded, NodeStyleMouseOver, NodeStyleSelected, NodeVerticalSpacing, RenderMode, RightToLeft, SelectedPathConnector, SelectionBox, SelectionBoxBorderColor, SelectionBoxFillColor, SelectionBoxSize, Styles, TabIndex, TabStop, Tag, Text, UseWaitCursor, Visible

(ApplicationSettings)

- (PropertyBinding)

(DataBindings)

- (Advanced), Tag, Text

AutoScrollMargin, AutoScrollMinSize, ExpandButtonSize, MaxixmumSize, MinimumSize, Size

- Width, Height

BackgroundStyle, NodeStyle *[(ApplicationSettings), GenerateMember, Modifiers]*

- BackColor, BackColor2, BackColorBlend, BackColorGradientAngle, BackColorGradientType, BackgroundImage, BackgroundImageAlpha, BackgroundImagePosition, Border, BorderBottom, BorderBottomColor, BorderBottomWidth, BorderColor, BorderColor2, BorderColorLight, BorderColorLight2, BorderGradientAngle, BorderLeft, BorderLeftColor, BorderLeftWidth, BorderLightGradientAngle, BorderRight, BorderRightColor, BorderRightWidth, BorderTop, BorderTopColor, BorderTopWidth, BorderWidth, Class, CornerDiameter, CornerType, CornerTypeBottomLeft, CornerTypeBottomRight, CornerTypeTopLeft, CornerTypeTopRight, Description, **Font**, MarginBottom, MarginLeft, MarginRight, MarginTop, MaximumHeight, MaximumWidth, Name, PaddingBottom, PaddingLeft, PaddingRight, PaddingTop, TextAlignment, TextColor, TextLineAlignment, TextShadowColor, TextTrimming, WordWrap
- TextShadowOffset

  - X, Y

Font

- Name, Size, Unit, Bold, GdiChartSet, GdiVerticalFont, Italic, Strikeout, Underline

LinkConnector, NodesConnector, RootConnector

- **(ApplicationSettings)**, (Name), ConnectorType, EndCap, **EndCapSize**, GenerateMember, LineColor, LineWidth, Modifiers, UnderlineNoBorderNode

Margin, Padding

- All, Left, Top, Right, Bottom

You have some properties for every node like **CheckBoxVisible *[Boolean]*** [image: A Node with Checkbox].

You can see all properties of every node in the following:

CellLayout, CellPartLayout, Cells, CheckBoxAlignment, CheckBoxVisible, Checked, CommandButton, ContextMenu, DataKeyString, DragDropEnabled, Enabled, Expanded, ExpandedVisibility, GenerateMember, HostedControl, Image, ImageAlignment, ImageExpanded, ImageExpandedIndex, ImageIndex, ImageMouseOver, ImageMouseOverIndex, LinkedNodes, Modifiers, Nodes, NodesColumns, ParentConnector, ParentConnectorPoints, RenderMode, Selectable, Style, StyleExpanded, StyleMouseOver, StyleSelected, TagString, Text, Visible

(ApplicationSettings)

- (PropertyBinding)

You can see more information about TreeGX control from following link:

[Visualize decision trees, create mind maps and more with TreeGX](http://www.devcomponents.com/treegx/)

Comment: Is it possible to turn the tree "sideways" as OP is trying to achieve? Also, those components are not free to use. However, A fully functional trial-version is available, so it is possible for OP to try these components before buying them.

Comment: I think that TreeGX can't turn to Vertical mode.
you can download 30 day fully functional trial release of DevComponents from following links:
TreeGX Trial Version Download: http://www.devcomponents.com/downloads/TreeGXSetupTrial.msi
DotNetBar for Windows Forms Fully Functional Trial Download: http://www.devcomponents.com/downloads/DotNetBarSetupTrial.msi
DotNetBar for WPF: http://www.devcomponents.com/downloads/DotNetBarWPFSetupTrial.msi
DotNetBar for Silverlight: http://www.devcomponents.com/downloads/DotNetBarSilverlightSetupTrial.msi

Answer (score 3):

Might take a look at this, I just glanced at it after finding it but looks like it might fit your needs, or could be altered to do so:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20508/Tree-Chart-Generator

Comment: this would work but it needs to scroll down and sideways. also is that a picture that it creates?

Comment: Yes, the component in the article is used to create images of the tree-structure. What do you mean by "scroll down and sideways"? And should the nodes be selectable and/or collapsible, as with a TreeView control?